# Error when working with spatial data in R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I am getting a couple errors when trying with my data that I can't seem to debug.

Here is the **R** script https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28231177/This%20Should%20Work.R
Here is the data https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28231177/my_data.csv

Here are the last couple lines that contain the errors when I run them:

```
pds <- fortify(sf_map)
# Using OBJECTID to define regions.
pds$OBJECTID <- as.integer(pds$OBJECTID)
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "OBJECTID", value = integer(0)) : 
# replacement has 0 rows, data has 16249


### Make the map

p1 <- ggplot(my_data, aes(map_id = zip))
p1 <- p1 + geom_map(aes(fill=vol, map_id = zip), map = pds)
p1 <- p1 + expand_limits(x = pds$lon, y = pds$lat) + coord_equal()
p1 + xlab("Basic Map with Default Elements")
# Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

Comment: Also, here is the shapefile http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28231177/sfzipcodes.zip

Comment: What is names(pds)? I dare say that OBJECTID is not one of them. The line pds$OBJECTID <- as.integer(pds$OBJECTID) assumes that column is there, checking that assumption is easy enough.

Comment: @mdsumner, this is what I get:  
`pds <- fortify(sf_map)
# Using OBJECTID to define regions.
names(pds)
#[1] "long"  "lat"   "order" "hole"  "piece" "group" "id"`

Looks like you're right.  Which column is that supposed to be set to? id?

Comment: I changed OBJECTID to id and am not seeing the first error (`"Error in $<-.data.frame...`).

I am still getting the second error with a blank plot :(

Comment: try long not lon, debugging is boring but pay careful attention and it won't take long

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me if you set

```
pds <- fortify(sf_map, region = "ID")
```

and removing the line

```
pds$OBJECTID <- as.integer(pds$OBJECTID)
```

Also you should use `long` not `lon` as mentioned by @mdsumner.

Here is a slightly different solution (using `geom_polygon` not `geom_map`)

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

## 'fortify' needs 'library(gpclib)' locally available
gpclibPermit()

## Import the shapefile
sf_map <- readShapeSpatial("sfzipcodes", ID = "ID")

## Import the data
my_data <- read.csv("my_data.csv")
my_data <- unique(my_data)

## Merge the data
sf_df <- fortify(sf_map, region='ID')
sf_df <- merge(sf_df, my_data, by.x="id", by.y="zip", all=FALSE)
sf_df <- sf_df[order(sf_df$group, sf_df$order), ]

## Make the map
p2 <- ggplot(sf_df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=vol))
p2 <- p2 + geom_polygon() + coord_equal()
p2 <- p2 + xlab("Basic Map with Default Elements")
p2
```